# Android:UI design problem

Tags: android, user-interface

in my app i am trying to get the following designs.

[image]
Above is the first image
[image]
Above is the second image

When the activity is opened the first image is shown, currently i have shown it as an tab bar but i am not able to place an red colored rounded imageview near the `Why?` button. According to my app the number in the rounded image view must get changed often.

When the next Why? button is clicked i want to show the UI as in second image with another three buttons over it.

In ios apps, this design can be made by the help of UISegmentControl. In android apps how to implement this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the nice tutorial about Tab activity and also put badge inside it

see below link

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147216/how-to-make-bottom-bar-or-navigation-bar-like-iphone-like-mytubo-on-android/7212685#7212685)